# django image upload help

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a template where the user can input data about himself, and upload his photo. Photo uploading will be done using ajax, with a separate upload button inside the form. My question is how do I upload the photo (when the user clicks on the upload button) and then save the user info when the user clicks on the submit button.

The model looks like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # some other fields
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="assets/images")
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you submit the form, and in the view save it if it is valid, everything should be saved into your db. Are you getting errors or what is the problem?

Comment: no, i am not getting an error. the thing is, the photo upload process is separate from submitting the entire form. the photo should be uploaded first, and the when the user clicks on submit, the form should be saved.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to use ajax to upload the image first? If you use Django's ImageField, like you are, and a user chooses a path to upload and fills out your other info and hits submit, all should be saved and then can be displayed on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the id of the User instance you used to save the picture as part of your js callback/success function, use it to populate a hidden field, and then call that user instance and save the rest of the info when the user submits the form.

The bigger question is, especially given that the user is going to submit the form anyway, why do you want to save just the image first?

Comment: thanks, but i forgot to mention that some fields are required. How can I save the image first, if the model requires me to proved all the required fields? As for your question, it's just the requirement of the site i'm building.

Comment: I see. There's two ways you could do this, you could create the User instance using placeholder data, since you know you're going to overwrite it once the user submits the form, but that would create some unused user profiles for those users that upload an image and never submit the form. Your other option would be to create a new Image model class which allows you to upload and store the image, return the id for the image, and use that when saving your new User instance when the form is submitted. I think option 2 might actually work best.

Comment: cool, but what happens to all the photos that were uploaded but never tied to any profile? is there any way to keep track of those photo or remove them after a while?

Comment: yeah, you could actually do this when creating the user instance. After the user account is created, you could delete the photo associated with that account in the Image table, and also delete all images where the upload date is over a day old (meaning that the user abandoned the form before signing up.)

Comment: You could have a cron or Celery task that periodically clears out any photos that didn't get associated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an `<input type="button" />` with a JavaScript event handler to process the upload. jQuery's $.POST can do this very easily for you.

If you use an `<input type="submit" />` for the image upload, it will also submit its containing form.

You will probably want to disable the actual "save" button until the ajax process has finished and that record has been saved, in case you need to make any associations to other data from your form, etc.

Hope that gets you going.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am having a difficulty with setting up the view so that I can upload the photo first (maybe, in a tmp dir), then upload the user info on submit.

Comment: You're welcome. I would probably point the upload post to a separate url/view to keep the view logic simpler.